# Where do I have to pay taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, united-kingdom, non-resident

I'm a Canadian citizen doing a rotational program with an international company based in UK. I'm paid by the American holdings office, and I was living and working in California between September '14 and March '15 (<6 months in this calendar/fiscal year). I'm currently working in the UK until September (<6 months) at which point I will move move to China.

Where the heck am I supposed to file taxes? How do I prove to the other countries that I shouldn't be paying taxes there?

Further details:

I'm apparently no longer a resident of Canada (according to my father and some tax-related decision he made). I also haven't lived there since 2009.

I am currently on an OPT (optional practical training) F1 visa to America with a pending STEM extension. I paid taxes in the USA last year, but because the F1 is a student visa I was a non-resident alien.

I wont live in any country for greater than 6 months this year.

Help!